# Constrains relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, constraint

I have the following design. Each *user* has it's own *contacts*, it's own *hosts* and assign those to a *domain* which belongs only to him.

I want to insure that the *host* you assign to the *domain* belongs to the *user* that *domain* is assigned to.

Is it something that I have to insure in my application logic?

If I set `domains.user_id` `foreign key` to reference `host.user_id` and `user_id.id` does it eliminate my issue?

[image]

By the way can anyone suggest me a better design for my schema?

Comment: See this similar problem: [Many to Many and Weak Entities](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities/34050#34050)

Comment: Are domains assigned to hosts and contacts? And for every domain, the user of its host and the user of its contact should be one and the same (user)?

Comment: In other words: Say that I am a contact of a particular user. Can I get a domain that belongs to a **different** user?

Comment: Then the linked question above provides an answer. One last question. Can you have domains that are "free", not assigned (to hosts or users)?

Comment: Ok,although I'm little bit confused, I'll try to explain to you. The difference I see with the link you provided to me is that it has many *artists* to many *albums* while mine *domains*,*hosts*,*contacts* are on one *user* and only. As for your last question *domain* can only exist without *host*.

Comment: It's `1 artist : many albums` actually. It's the same diamond shape with user (or artist) at the top. The only differences may lie with whether an album track can exist without a track or an album (it cannot) which may not be the case with your requirements.

Comment: @ypercube Oh,sorry I meant `albums` and `tracks`. I see a `many to many` relationship in this example,while in mine I can't see one.

Comment: A contact can have may domains and a host can have many domains, right? So the `domains` entity is basically a many to many relationship between contacts and hosts.

Comment: @ypercube A *contact* of a *user* can be assign to multiple *domains* of that specific *user* and only,but a *domain* of that *user* can be assigned only to **one** *contact* of that *user*.The same to *hosts*. Isn't that a `one to many` relationship? Or I am fundamentally wrong?

Comment: One to many between contacts and domains, correct. One to many between hosts and domains, too. I was talking about the (implied) relationship. between contacts and hosts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10521/discussion-between-ypercube-and-yannis-hristofakis)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a rather common problem, when the design has a "diamond" shape. See similar questions:
[Many to Many and Weak Entities](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities/34050#34050)

With MySQL, I'd use something like this:

<sup>(0)</sup> Note that I prefer `user_id` as name for the primary key of `users` and not `id` for all the tables. I find the SQL code totally confusing otherwise (plus you can use the `JOIN ... USING (tablename_id)` syntax).

<sup>(1)</sup> The extra `UNIQUE` constraints in tables `hosts` and `contacts` are needed for the foreign keys from the `domains` table.
<sup>(2)</sup> The two `FOREIGN KEY` constraints from the `domains` table are changed to use composite keys (include the `user_id`).

Table **`users`**

```
CREATE TABLE users
( user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
-- other columns
, PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ;
```

Table **`contacts`**

```
CREATE TABLE contacts
( contact_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, user_id INT NOT NULL
, info TEXT
, PRIMARY KEY (contact_id)
, UNIQUE INDEX (user_id, contact_id)       -- added, see comment 1 above
, INDEX (user_id)
, FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES users (user_id)
) ;
```

Table **`hosts`**

```
CREATE TABLE hosts
( host_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, user_id INT NOT NULL
, name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
--
, PRIMARY KEY (host_id)
, UNIQUE INDEX (user_id, host_id)          -- added, see comment 1 above
, INDEX (user_id)
, FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES users (user_id)
) ;
```

Table **`domains`**

```
CREATE TABLE domains
( domain_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, user_id INT NOT NULL
, contact_id INT NOT NULL
, host_id INT NULL                       -- nullable based on comments
, name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
-- other columns
, PRIMARY KEY (domain_id)
, FOREIGN KEY (user_id, contact_id)       -- composite FK, see comment 2
    REFERENCES contacts (user_id, contact_id)
, FOREIGN KEY (user_id, host_id)          -- composite FK, see comment 2
    REFERENCES hosts (user_id, host_id)
) ;
```

Comment: @ypercube I see you used a composite reference key, but why you didn't use a composite primary key for *hosts* and *contacts*, like I did?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the composite key is primary or unique. If the columns are not null, there is no difference. Either can be referenced by foreign keys from other tables.

Comment: The choice of primary key matters only in the specific implementation (MySQL's InnoDB engine uses the primary key as clustered key of the table). But that is about the physical design of the table, not the logical design.