# Which of these database designs is normalized?

Tags: database-design

I have two possible database designs.

A) a many-to-many relationship between `Branches` and `FiscalYears` via a dedicated join table `FiscalYearsBranches`

B) two (or more) many-to-many relationships between `Branches` and `FiscalYears` via other tables (`Documents`, `Factors`, etc.)

See the diagrams below. Which of these designs is better and why?

---

**Design A:**  a many-to-many relationship between `Branches` and `FiscalYears` via a dedicated join table `FiscalYearsBranches`

---

[image]

---

**Design B:** two (or more) many-to-many relationships between `Branches` and `FiscalYears` via other tables (`Documents`, `Factors`, etc.)

---

[image]

Comment: Both are equally ugly.

Comment: Please get rid of the sample tables, they're really confusing the picture.

Comment: Is a fiscal year really bound to a company?  (I am no financial expert, just asking.)  If yes, what will prevent you from coupling a fiscal year of company X with a branch of company Y?

Comment: And the word is "Branches", not "Branchs".

Comment: What @dezso noticed is right. You probably need to include the `CompanyID` in the `FiscalYearsBranches` table - and modify the FKs accordingly - to avoid that issue. Check this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49513/constrains-relationship/49516#49516

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? It looks good.

Comment: @ypercube: My answer is not answer of my question. I only normalize design A. I can normalize design B like that. (English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part.)

Comment: Well, the title has *"Which of these database designs is normalized?" and the question has *"Which of these designs is better?"* About normalization, I don't see any problem with either design. They just model slightly different things, as Matthew answered.

Comment: The question of whether Fiscal Year is dependent on company or not is a subject matter question.  In my experience, different companies have different fiscal calendars, but a single company uses a single fiscal calendar throughout its branches (except during mergers and takeovers).  So I would answer yes, but.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design A implies a relationship between `FiscalYears` and `Branches` which exists separately to the relationships between these tables and `Documents` and `Factors`. This relationship is recorded in `FiscalYearsBranches`

Design B does not do this, it only defines relationships between `FiscalYears` and `Branches` via `Documents` and `Factors`.

You should think about the relationship between `FiscalYears` and `Branches`: if this exists, as a real life relationship you can talk about outside of the database, even when you're not looking at `Documents` or `Factors`, then go with A. If not, go with B, otherwise you are suggesting that this relationship exists when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @dezso and @ypercube comments, I think correct design is:

Table Companies:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companies] (
    [Id]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [Code] NCHAR (10)     NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Companies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Table FiscalYears:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FiscalYears] (
    [Id]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId]  INT            NOT NULL,
    [Name]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate]  DATE           NOT NULL,
    [FinishDate] DATE           NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_FiscalYears] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_FiscalYears] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC, [CompanyId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Companies_FiscalYears] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([Id])
);
```

Table Branches:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Branches] (
    [Id]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Code]      NCHAR (10)     NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Branches] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_Branches] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC, [CompanyId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Companies_Branchs] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([Id])
);
```

Table FiscalYearsBranchs:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FiscalYearsBranchs] (
    [Id]           INT NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId]    INT NOT NULL,
    [FiscalYearId] INT NOT NULL,
    [BranchId]     INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_FiscalYearsBranchs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_FiscalYearsBranchs_FiscalYears] FOREIGN KEY ([FiscalYearId], [CompanyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[FiscalYears] ([Id], [CompanyId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_FiscalYearsBranchs_Branches] FOREIGN KEY ([BranchId], [CompanyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Branches] ([Id], [CompanyId])
);
```

Table Documents:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents] (
    [Id]                    INT  NOT NULL,
    [FiscalYearsBranchesId] INT  NOT NULL,
    [No]                    INT  NOT NULL,
    [Date]                  DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Documents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Documents_FiscalYearsBranchs] FOREIGN KEY ([FiscalYearsBranchesId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[FiscalYearsBranchs] ([Id])
);
```

Table Factors:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Factors] (
    [Id]                    INT  NOT NULL,
    [FiscalYearsBranchesId] INT  NOT NULL,
    [No]                    INT  NOT NULL,
    [Date]                  DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Factors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Factors_FiscalYearsBranchs] FOREIGN KEY ([FiscalYearsBranchesId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[FiscalYearsBranchs] ([Id])
);
```

---

[image]

Comment: This one still has the same problem I asked about.

Comment: @dezso. I've tested and I think the problem is solved. It is possible to explain more?

Answer (score 0):

I think the company determines the fiscal year, not the other way around.  This is based on my experience with companies.  Your experience may be different.

Hence, I would put an FK to FiscalYearId in the Companies table, and not put any FKs in the fiscal year table.

However, I would put two separate entries in the FiscalYears table for two different companies, even if their fiscal years coincide.  This may seem redundant, but it will come in handy when one company changes its fiscal year, and the other company doesn't.

As far as whether Branches, Documents and Factors should include FiscalYearId or not, that question is based on the functional dependencies in your case,  ones that I do not know.  If Branches, Factors and Documents all use the company's Fiscal calendar, then it's more normalized to leave the FiscalYearId out of those tables.  But if each item uses its own FiscalYear, then  you have to include the FiscalYearId as an FK in the corresponding table.