# Enforcing constraints "two tables away"

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, referential-integrity, polymorphic-associations

I ran into some trouble modeling an electrical schematic in SQL.
The structure I'd like to capture is

```
  part ←────────── pin
   ↑                ↑
part_inst ←───── pin_inst
```

where "inst" is short for "instance".

For example, I might have as a `part` an LM358 op-amp with `pin`s
1OUT, 1IN-, 1IN+, GND, 2IN+, 2IN-, 2OUT, and V<sub>CC</sub>. I might
then place this part on a schematic, creating a `part_inst` and 8
`pin_inst`s.

Ignoring data fields, my initial attempt at a schema was

```
create table parts (
    part_id bigserial primary key
);
create table pins (
    pin_id bigserial primary key,
    part_id bigint not null references parts
);
create table part_insts (
    part_inst_id bigserial primary key,
    part_id bigint not null references parts
);
create table pin_insts (
    pin_inst_id bigserial primary key,
    part_inst_id bigint not null references part_insts,
    pin_id bigint not null references pins
);
```

The main problem with this schema is that a `pin_inst` might be tied
to a `part_inst` with `part_id=1` but its `pin` has `part_id=2`.

I'd like to avoid this problem on the database level rather than the
application level. So, I modified my primary keys to enforce that.
I marked the changed lines with `--`.

```
create table parts (
    part_id bigserial primary key
);
create table pins (
    pin_id bigserial,                                          --
    part_id bigint not null references parts,
    primary key (pin_id, part_id)                              --
);
create table part_insts (
    part_inst_id bigserial,                                    --
    part_id bigint not null references parts,
    primary key (part_inst_id, part_id)                        --
);
create table pin_insts (
    pin_inst_id bigserial primary key,
    part_inst_id bigint not null,                              --
    pin_id bigint not null,                                    --
    part_id bigint not null references parts,                  --
    foreign key (part_inst_id, part_id) references part_insts, --
    foreign key (pin_id, part_id) references pins              --
);
```

My gripe with this method is that it pollutes the primary keys:
Everywhere I refer to a `part_inst`, I need to keep track of both the
`part_inst_id` and the `part_id`. Is there another way I can go about enforcing the constraint
`pin_inst.part_inst.part_id = pin_inst.pin.part_id` without being overly verbose?

Comment: Two things: (a) doesn't 1OUT, 1IN-, 1IN+, GND, 2IN+, 2IN-, 2OUT, and VCC yield 11 pin instances? (b) I don't  get your initial schema. Can't a pin be used in more than one part? You need a N-N relationship between pin and part not a 1-N.

Comment: @user34332: (a) The numbers are part of the names. For example, "2OUT" is a single pin. Here's a [schematic drawing](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Lm358.gif) of the [chip](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/Lm356.jpg/287px-Lm356.jpg) I'm talking about in the question. (b) I disagree. Certainly two parts might have a VCC (positive supply voltage, "voltage [at] common collector") pin, but they're logically different pins. For example, one VCC pin might typically draw 500 µA and a different one 250 µA.

Comment: [Closely related question.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Minimal solution

A radical solution would be to remove `pin_inst` completely:

```
  part ←────────── pin
    ↑               ↑
part_inst ←───── pin_inst
```

There is nothing in your question to suggest you actually need the redundant table. For `pin`s associated to a `part_inst`, look at the `pin`s of the associated `part`.

That would simplify the code to:

```
CREATE TABLE part (   -- with singular terms as table names
  part_id      bigserial PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE pin (
  pin_id       bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
, part_id      bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES part
);
CREATE TABLE part_inst (
  part_inst_id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
, part_id      bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES part
);
```

<sup>But your comment made clear that we won't get away with that ...</sup>

#### Alternative if `pin_inst` is needed

You cannot reference a table “two tables away” with [foreign key constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK). Including `part_id` like you did is the simplest solution with foreign key constraints.

But you can at least make do without "polluting" the primary keys. Add  [`UNIQUE` constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS).

(Updated with modern syntax for Postgres 14.)

```
CREATE TABLE part (
  part_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE pin (
  pin_id       bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, part_id      bigint NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT pin_part_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (part_id) REFERENCES part
, CONSTRAINT pin_fk_uni UNIQUE (part_id, pin_id)  -- only for FK; note leading part_id
);

CREATE TABLE part_inst (
  part_inst_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, part_id      bigint NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT part_inst_part_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (part_id) REFERENCES part
, CONSTRAINT part_inst_fk_uni UNIQUE (part_id, part_inst_id)  -- only for FK
);

CREATE TABLE pin_inst (
  pin_inst_id  bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, part_inst_id bigint NOT NULL
, pin_id       bigint NOT NULL
, part_id      bigint NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT pin_fkey       FOREIGN KEY (part_id, pin_id)       REFERENCES pin (part_id, pin_id)
, CONSTRAINT part_inst_fkey FOREIGN KEY (part_id, part_inst_id) REFERENCES part_inst (part_id, part_inst_id)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=236b7e8d81879cd887b676567c60087e)*

The bold `UNIQUE` constraints are logically redundant, but required as target for the bold `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

I put `part_id` first in the unique constraints (and consequently in the FK constraints, too). That is irrelevant for referential integrity, but it matters for performance. The primary keys already implement indexes for the PK columns. It's better to have the *other* column first in the multicolumn indexes implementing the `UNIQUE` constraints. See:

- [Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field)
- [Many to Many and Weak Entities](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities)

Related questions on SO:

- [Can a multi-field UNIQUE constraint include fields from more than one table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11938564/939860)
- [Foreign key constraint with some column values residing in other tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21791675/939860)

#### Alternative with triggers

You could resort to triggers functions, which are more flexible, but a bit more complicated and error prone and a bit less strict. The benefit: you could do without `part_inst.part_id` and `pin.part_id` ...

Comment: Do we even need `unique(part_id, pin_id)`? Seeing as `pin_id` is a primary key, aren't we guaranteed that it will only be associated with a single `part_id`?

Comment: @Gili: Those `UNIQUE` constraints are logically redundant, but required. I clarified the explanation above. While being at it, I also revised the main solution and brought it up to date.