# Non-overlapping rectangles constrained to a boundary

Tags: postgresql, database-design, spatial, referential-integrity, exclusion-constraint

I am trying to model placement of parts on a circuit board. Without any
meaningful constraints, my basic schema looks like this:

```
create table part (
    part_id bigserial primary key,
    name text not null,
    width double precision not null,
    height double precision not null
);
create table board (
    board_id bigserial primary key,
    width double precision not null,
    height double precision not null
);
create table board_part (
    board_id bigint not null references board,
    part_id bigint not null references part,
    position point not null
);
```

<sup>([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1cfb7/5), [Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89w7d.jpg))</sup>

For `b` and `b2` any `board_part`s, I want to enforce the following
constraints:

1. `b` lies on the board:

   ```
   box(b.position, point(b.part.width,b.part.height))
       <@ box(point(0,0), point(b.board.width,b.board.height))
   ```
2. `b` and `b2` do not overlap if they lie on the same board:

   ```
   b.board_id != b2.board_id or
   not (box(b.position, point(b.part.width,b.part.height))
           && box(b2.position, point(b2.part.width,b2.part.height)))
   ```

**How can I achieve this (without too much data duplication)?** Changing the schema is fine.

Here is [my best attempt (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5773c/2), taking
inspiration from
Erwin's [answer to my previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58972/34321).
It enforces the constraints I wanted, but has a lot of duplicate data in the `board_part` table. I imagine I could write a function to fill in the `board_width`, `board_height`, `part_width`, and `part_height` fields automatically, but it still feels wrong having so much duplicate data around. Also, keying to the `width`/`height` fields feels like a hack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Basic answer

I suggest the [geometric type **`box`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-CONV-TABLE) and an [**exclusion constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) (Postgres **9.2+**). Should be the *perfect* solution to your problem. It creates a GiST index implicitly that also supports certain queries.

Combine it with with equality on `board_id` to allow multiple boards in a single table. You'll need the additional module [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html). Once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

To confine parts to a board add a [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS). You need the confining box of the board in the `board_part` table (redundantly). Could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE board_part (
  board_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES board
, board_box box NOT NULL
, part_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES part
, part_box box NOT NULL
, EXCLUDE USING gist (board_id WITH =, part_box WITH &&)
, CHECK (part_box <@ board_box)
);
```

[`&&` .. "overlaps" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-OP-TABLE)
[`<@` .. "contained" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-OP-TABLE)

The drawback: you need the dimensions of each part and box in table `board_part` redundantly.

### Advanced answer

To avoid redundant storage, I like this new idea better: Fake `IMMUTABLE` functions returning the box for an id and build constraints upon these functions. Your tables can make do with just the columns of your original design.

I ran a complete test to verify it works.

#### Complete schema

Base tables:

```
CREATE TABLE part (
  part_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, part text NOT NULL
, wide int NOT NULL
, high int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE board (
  board_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, board text NOT NULL
, wide int NOT NULL
, high int NOT NULL
);
```

`IMMUTABLE` functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_boardbox(_board_id int)
  RETURNS box
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT box(point(0,0), point (b.wide, b.high))
 FROM   public.board b WHERE board_id = $1'; 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_partbox(_part_id int, _wide int, _high int)
  RETURNS box
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT box(point($2,$3), point($2 + p.wide, $3 + p.high))
 FROM   public.part p WHERE part_id = $1';
```

Replace `public` with the actual schema of your tables.
In Postgres 9.6 or later add `PARALLEL SAFE`. See:

- [When to mark functions as PARALLEL RESTRICTED vs PARALLEL SAFE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251274/when-to-mark-functions-as-parallel-restricted-vs-parallel-safe)

Main table:

```
CREATE TABLE board_part (
  board_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES board
, part_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES part
, wide int NOT NULL
, high int NOT NULL
, EXCLUDE USING gist (board_id WITH =, f_partbox(part_id, wide, high) WITH &&)
, CHECK (f_partbox(part_id, wide, high) <@ f_boardbox(board_id))
);
```

Of course, if you update dimensions for a `board_id` or `part_id` in use, you partly void the index and / or constraint. You would need to recreate any index or constraint building on the promise that the return value of `IMMUTABLE` function never change. See:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)

However, you can avoid this expensive operation with triggers to update only affected rows:

#### Triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_board_upaft()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE board_part
   SET    board_id = board_id        -- enough to trigger CHECK constraint
   WHERE  board_id = NEW.board_id;   -- limit to relevant rows

   RETURN NULL;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER board_upaft
AFTER UPDATE OF wide, high ON board  -- limit to relevant columns
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_board_upaft();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_part_upaft()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE board_part
   SET    part_id = 0
   WHERE  part_id = NEW.part_id;

   UPDATE board_part
   SET    part_id = NEW.part_id
   WHERE  part_id = 0;               -- enough to update EXCL. constraint

   RETURN NULL;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER part_upaft
AFTER UPDATE OF wide, high ON part
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_part_upaft();
```

`part_id = 0` is a special row in table `part` with size 0. Needed for the trigger.

Test data:

```
INSERT INTO board (board, wide, high)
VALUES ('b1010',10,10), ('b2030',20, 30);

INSERT INTO part (part_id, part, wide, high)
VALUES (0,'p0',0,0);          -- special row needed for trigger!

INSERT INTO part (part, wide, high)
VALUES ('p11',1,1), ('p33',3,3);

INSERT INTO board_part (board_id, part_id, wide, high)
VALUES (1,1,3,3)
     , (1,1,5,5)   -- no overlap, inside board
     , (2,1,3,3);  -- different board, no overlap
```

#### Test

These must raise exceptions if the triggers & constraints do their job:

```
UPDATE part SET wide = 6 , high = 6
WHERE  part_id = 1;            -- violates EXCL. & CHECK constraint

UPDATE part SET wide = 3 , high = 3
WHERE  part_id = 1;            -- violates EXCL. constraint

UPDATE board SET wide = 2 , high = 2
WHERE  board_id = 1;            -- violates CHECK constraint
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5c6a79e55cd33bce9ab72b17c171eddf)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dfc97/1)</sub>

Comment: That looks pretty similar to what I came up with, apart from the use of `box` instead of scalar width/height. The problem with this approach is how ugly the foreign keys get when you try to enforce that `width(b.part_box) = b.part.width and height(b.part_box) = b.part.height` (I apologize for not making it clear that I wanted to enforce that.)

I'll look into your suggestion to use triggers. I'm not very familiar with triggers, so I'll return to this in a day or two when I get the basics down.

Thanks for all your help on this!

Comment: @Snowball: I added a new idea to avoid redundant columns.