# Postgres constraint function on a single column

Tags: postgresql, constraint

Is it possible to create a constraint in Postgres that will run a function, but only if a specific column is changed?

Right now, I have this:

```
ALTER TABLE public.employee
  ADD CONSTRAINT pin_is_unique_in_company CHECK 
     (fn_pin_is_unique_in_company(id, company_id, pin));
```

I only want this to run if the pin column has been modified.

Comment: why not use trigger in this case?

Comment: You would need to provide a lot more details to allow us to find the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CHECK` constraints should *always* evaluate to the same result. If your function is declared `IMMUTABLE` it's a perfect candidate, else there is more to discuss here. A `NOT VALID` constraint might be an option. Consider:

- [Disable all constraints and table checks while restoring a dump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/disable-all-constraints-and-table-checks-while-restoring-a-dump/75635#75635)

However, a `CHECK` constraint is run *unconditionally*. If you want to run the check only if a specific column has been changed, you need a different tool. One obvious candidate would be a [**trigger**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html), [like @a_vlad commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123471/postgres-constraint-function-on-a-single-column#comment227089_123471):

```
CREATE TRIGGER employee_upbef
BEFORE UPDATE OF pin ON public.employee
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_pin_is_unique_in_company();
```

In Postgres 9.1 or later you can restrict the trigger to the change of specific columns.
You can't pass parameters per row to a trigger function, though. Instead reference the [special row variable `NEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html) inside the trigger function ...

Related example:

- [Non-overlapping rectangles constrained to a boundary](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59399/non-overlapping-rectangles-constrained-to-a-boundary/59402#59402)

**However**, What you are trying to do sounds like a case for a multicolumn [**`UNIQUE` constraint**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS). There is not enough information to tell.