# Conditional Foreign Key Relationship

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, constraint

I currently have a foreign key between two entities, and I would like to make that relation conditional to the entityType of one of the tables.  Here's the hierachy of tables, *this is done via FK refrences from child to parent*

```
                  Store
            /                \
  Employees                    \
                             TransactionalStores
                            /       |         \
                     Kiosks         |          BrickMortars
                                 Onlines
```

I currently have a FK relation from Employee to store

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ADD CONSTRAINT Employee_Store
            FOREIGN KEY (TransStoreId)
            REFERENCES TransactionalStores(StoreId)
```

I would like to add the conditional:

```
WHERE TransactionalStores.storeType != 'ONLINE_TYPE'
```

Is this possible or must I subclass TransactionalStores into two new subTypes (e.g. PhysicalStores and VirtualStores)

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34040/3684, http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/58970/3684

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Foreign keys *can* be made conditional...sort of. You don't show the layout of each table, so here is a typical design showing your relationships:

```
create table TransactionalStores(
    ID        int   not null auto_increment,
    StoreType char  not null,
    ..., -- other data
    constraint CK_TransStoreType check( StoreType in( 'B', 'K', 'O' )),
    constraint PK_TransactionalStores primary key( ID ),
    constraint UQ_TransStoreTypes unique( ID, StoreType ) -- for FK references
);
create table Kiosks(
    ID         int   not null,
    StoreType  char  not null,
    ..., -- other Kiosk data
    constraint CK_KioskStoreType check( StoreType = 'K' ), -- kiosks only
    constraint PK_Kiosks primary key( ID, StoreType ),
    constraint FK_Kiosks_TransStores foreign key( ID, StoreType )
        references TransactionalStores( ID, StoreType )
);
```

The Onlines and BrickMorters would have the same basic structure but with StoreType constrained to only 'O' or 'B' as appropriate.

Now you want a reference from another table to TransactionalStores (and through it to the various store tables) but limited to Kiosks and BrickMorter. The only difference would be in the constraint:

```
create table Employees(
    ID         int       not null,
    StoreID    int,
    StoreType  char,
    ..., -- other Employee data
    constraint PK_Employees primary key( ID ),
    constraint CK_Employees_StoreType check( coalesce( StoreType, 'X' ) <> 'O' )), -- Online not allowed
    constraint FK_Employees_TransStores foreign key( StoreID, StoreType )
        references TransactionalStores( ID, StoreType )
);
```

In this table, the FK reference forces StoreType to be either 'K', 'O' or 'B' but the field constraint further limits it to only 'K' or 'B'.

For illustration, I've used a check constraint to limit the store types in the TransactionStores table. In real life, a StoreTypes lookup table with StoreType being a FK to that table would probably be a better design choice.

Comment: Would it be more efficient to set the key as `StoreType, StoreID` instead of `StoreID, StoreType`? I would think that because there are fewer possible values of StoreType that this would be faster. Am I correct in thinking this? Or is it faster the way you have it because StoreID is a clustered index on the referenced table?

Answer (score 9):

A foreign key can't be made conditional so that is out of the question.  The business rule appears to be that an employee can work for one and only one **physical** store.  Given that, the super type of store has two sub-types as you suggested:  **Physical** and **Online**.  Each physical store may be staffed by one or more employees, and each employee must be assigned to one and only one physical store.  Physical stores then have two sub-types, **Brick and Mortar** and **Kiosk**.  Having three direct sub-types - **Kiosk**, **Online**, and **Brick and Mortar** - hides a property that is possessed by every store - whether or not it can be found at a physical location.  Now the design relies on a human to understand the **semantics** inherent in the sub-type names to understand that online stores don't have employees.  This is not readily apparent in the declared schema and **code** in the form of a trigger must be written to express that understanding in a way the DBMS can enforce.  Developing, testing, and maintaining a trigger that does not impact performance is a much more difficult solution to implement as is shown in the book [Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430242841).

Sub-typing **Store** first on its kind of location and **then** on the physical store's kind of structure is a more correct design with respect to the business rules and eliminates the need to write code to enforce the rule.  Once the property is clearly included as a store location type which can be used as a discriminator for the sub-types, the relationship can be made between employees and physical stores directly and thus fully implementing the rule just with the foreign key constraint.  ere is a data model created with [Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html) that shows the super and sub-typing using [Barker-Ellis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barker%27s_notation) box in box notation for super and sub-types, which I prefer for its elegant presentation.  The diagram can now clearly show the rule as well.

[image]