# Database design - passenger, driver, wallet. How to handle multiple foreign keys with Id and type fields?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key

I have to design a database schema for new project. I will use PostgreSQL for the implementation of the schema.

Right now I'm stuck in a scenario where I need to handle foreign keys based on `type` and `id`. Here are the tables:

`Passenger`:

```
PassengerID
FirstName
Email
DOB
Address
```

`Driver`:

```
DriverID
CNIC
Vehicle
License
Status
```

`Wallet`:

```
WalledID
Amount
UserId
UserType
```

**Problem:** I want that every `wallet` row should have `UserId` as `DriverId` or `PassengerID` and in the type field the name of the table.

How can I achieve this with PostgreSQL? I have heard that it is possible from polymorphic association but don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Check this thread: [Conditional Foreign Key Relationship](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113122/conditional-foreign-key-relationship)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have that directly, but you can do the following:

- Have two foreign key columns `driverid` and `passengerid` in `wallet` that reference the respective tables.
- Add a check constraint that force one of the foreign key columns `NULL` and the other `NOT NULL` based on `usertype`.

  ```
  CHECK (usertype = 'driver'    AND driverid IS NOT NULL AND passengerid IS NULL
      OR usertype = 'passenger' AND driverid IS NULL AND passengerid IS NOT NULL)
  ```
- If you want, add a view on `wallet` that uses `coalesce` to map both foreign key columns to a single one.

Comment: I have added an example for a check constraint.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to add a "supertype" of Driver and Passenger. In lack of a better name, I'll call it car_resident:

```
CREATE TABLE car_residents
( resident_id ... not null primary key
, resident_type char(1) not null
,     check (resident_type in ('P','D'))
,     unique (resident_type, resident_id)
, ... );

CREATE TABLE Passenger
( PassengerID ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, resident_type char(1) not null
,     CHECK check (resident_type = 'P')
,     FOREIGN KEY (resident_type, PassengerID)
          REFERENCES car_resident (resident_type, resident_id)
, ...
);

-- similar construct for Driver

CREATE TABLE Wallet
( ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, resident_id ... NOT NULL
, resident_type ... NOT NULL
, ...
,     FOREIGN KEY (resident_type, resident_id)
          REFERENCES car_resident (resident_type, resident_id)
);
```