# A question about foreign keys and many to many relationships

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations

My question is mostly conceptual in nature. I have a database schema that involves a many-to-many relationship between a School table and Student table. This seems sensible to me, given that a school can have many students, and a student can attend many schools. I'm hung up on the problem of whether to include the school as a foreign key in the tables that are directly beneath the Student table in the information hierarchy (Behavior, Attendance, Grade).

In short, the many-to-many relationship between School and Student allows for the possibility that a student referenced in the Attendance table would have multiple schools listed in the linked Student table. This could result in unwanted ambiguity when going over attendance records. (i.e. *Did they miss class in school A or school B?*) My solution is obvious: include a School foreign key for any tables beneath Student to make their relationship to a given school explicit.

[image: Ugly data flow]

The problem: this seems inelegant. Aesthete that I am, I would like the information to flow through tables, instead of jumping tables.  A convenient solution I've encountered would be to rely on a polymorphic association, wherein the primary key passed to the tables beneath Student (Behavior, Attendance, Grade) provides unique values for both the student and school. Unfortunately, it appears that SQL won't tolerate that approach.

Is there a solution that allows me to enjoy the apparently sensible data flow offered by polymorphic association (illustrated below) without breaking the rules of SQL, or am I trying to have my cake and eat it to? 
[image: preferred (pretty) data flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given that a school can have many students, and a student can attend many schools

.. you should have a **many-to-many relationship** between `school` and `student` - implemented as separate table. (`school_id` is misplaced in the table `student`.) I'll simply name it `school_student`:

```
CREATE TABLE school_student (
   school_student_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY  
 , school_id  int NOT NULL REFERENCES school
 , student_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES student
 , ...
);
```

And then use `school_student_id` in tables `behavior` and `attendance`.
**Alternatively**, you can use a [multicolumn PK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS) on `(school_id, student_id)` and carry over `(school_id, student_id)` as FK - effectively implementing what you had in mind - with **standard SQL**. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE school_student (
 , school_id  int NOT NULL REFERENCES school
 , student_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES student
 , ...
 , PRIMARY KEY (school_id, student_id)
);
```

You don't *need* that for `grade`, since that references a `course` bound to a `school` already. But you might implement something to enforce integrity so that students can only attend courses at schools they are enrolled at. If you use `(school_id, student_id)` as FK, that can be enforced automatically - using  a single copy of `school_id` for both FKs in table `grade`.

Related:

- [Enforcing constraints "two tables away"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58970/enforcing-constraints-two-tables-away/58972#58972)

Comment: Thank you! That clears up a lot of my confusion.

Comment: @M.Templeman What does this mean? `PRIMARY KEY (school_id, student_id)` , does it mean both school_id and student_id are primary key in junction table, because if it is true, how can these two foreign keys be primary because both of these foreign keys can repeat themselves?

Comment: @Yogie: It's a *multicolumn* PK. The *combination* of both columns is UNIQUE. Means that a student can only be registered at each school once. This is a standard many-to-many implementation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860