# Model multiple 1-m relationship to a single entity

Tags: database-design, erd

I have an entity called `Box`. This box has a `from` property which could be from a variety of different entities. It could be from a `user`, `office`, `import`, `storage` and many more.

So far I can think of two ways to model this:

Approach one:

```
| box_id | box_content | from_user | from_office | from_import | from_storage | ...  |
|--------|-------------|-----------|-------------|-------------|--------------|------|
| box_1  | apple       | user_a    | null        | null        | null         | null |
| box_2  | orange      | null      | null        | import_b    | null         | null |
```

Approach 2:

```
BOX
| box_id | box_content |
|--------|-------------|
| box_1  | apple       |
| box_2  | orange      |

USER
| user_id | name  |
|---------|-------|
| user_a  | Rick  |
| user_b  | David |

USER <-> BOX
| user_id | box_id |
|---------|--------|
| user_a  | box_1  |

IMPORT <-> BOX
| import_id | box_id |
|-----------|--------|
| import_a  | box_2  |
```

But I don't like either ways because in approach 1 there are so many `null` columns and in approach 2 I need to create a new relationship table every time there is a new `from` entity. Is there a better way to model this in a relational database?

Comment: What is wrong with null values?

Comment: @JoeW, the problem is they are mutually exclusive. Which means there is only one column with actual value at any point in time and the rest of the columns are all null.

Comment: Your preferred RDBMS and version? How many distinct `from` sources? How can those change over time? Do you want / need to enforce referential integrity? Roughly how many rows? Concurrent write operations from multiple users? Most important goals? performance / size / reliability / portability / simplicity?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, postgres 9.6. For now 4 distinct `from` but can grow to 10-20. They change rarely. Without referential integrity it would've been easy of course. Roughly 200K-500K. Concurrent write is needed. portability and simplicity is more important than performance and size.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the question to show these essential preferences / requirements prominently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up your added comment: Preferred RDBMS: Postgres 9.6, enforce referential integrity even under concurrent write load, at most 20 different sources, 500k rows, keep it simple.

Referential integrity is the hard part. The one rock solid way is with **foreign key constraints**. But you want to refer to one of multiple tables. From the same column?

- [How to have a foreign key pointing to two primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268886/how-to-have-a-foreign-key-pointing-to-two-primary-keys/42285952#42285952)

Short answer: not possible.

That leaves no other choice than either have one column for each source (your approach 1) or one table (your approach 2). Tables would make sense for a n:m relationship, not so much for 1:n. Your <strike>approach 2</strike> is too complex, wastes too much storage, and it does not even match your data model to begin with.

Leaves us with **approach 1**. You worry:

> the problem is they are mutually exclusive. Which means there is only one column with actual value at any point in time and the rest of the columns are all null.

1. *mutual exclusive* - enforce that with a simple `CHECK` constraint. Standard SQL, a bit verbose but fast.
2. *NULL storage* - is extremely cheap in Postgres. Basically, 1 bit in the NULL bitmap. Details:

   - [Do nullable columns occupy additional space in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147130/939860)

So I would do this (**Postgres** implementation):

```
CREATE TABLE box (
   box_id      serial PRIMARY KEY
 , box_content text -- NOT NULL?
 , from_user   int  REFERENCES users(user_id)
 , from_office int  REFERENCES office(office_id)
 , from_import int  REFERENCES import(import_id)
  -- more?
 , CONSTRAINT exactly_one_from
   CHECK (CASE WHEN from_user   IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN from_office IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN from_import IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = 1)
);
```

The `CHECK` constraints enforces *exactly* 1 reference, the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints enforce referential integrity under all circumstances.

If the many NULL columns are a burden to the human eye, consider a **`VIEW`** like:

```
CREATE VIEW box_view AS
SELECT box_id, box_content
     , COALESCE( from_user, from_office, from_import) AS from_id
     , CASE WHEN from_user   IS NOT NULL THEN 'user'
            WHEN from_office IS NOT NULL THEN 'office'
            WHEN from_import IS NOT NULL THEN 'import' END AS from_type
FROM   box;
```

Again, verbose but fast.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9709ba76f967bcf8ac32a9f49d98cece)*

There are many other possible approaches:

- A document type like `hstore` or `jsonb`.
- Multicolumn FK contraints like here:

  - [Enforcing constraints "two tables away"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58970/enforcing-constraints-two-tables-away/58972#58972)
- Enforce referential integrity with trigger instead of FK constraint.

But none of these guarantee referential integrity under concurrent write load like this approach does. Good performance and the smallest disk footprint are additional pros.
The downside: you have to alter the table definition (and view, queries, ...) for every additional "from" type.

Comment: Very thorough answer as usual. Thanks Erwin.

Answer (score 1):

My option would be

```
BOX(ID,descr)
USER(ID,....)
OFFICE(ID,...)
IMPORT(ID,...)
FROM(FROM_ID, office_id, user_id, import_id) FK ....
RELATION(FROM_ID, BOX_ID) fk FROM_ID references FROM, BOX_ID ref. BOX
```

To keep tables as clean as possible and not to have 'too many' little tables

EDIT:
You may choose to adopt 'talking codes' for from_id:

```
U123 if from user
O123 if from office
I123 if from import
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a third approach where you just note which source type and id is for each box.

```
| box_id | box_content | box_source | source    |
|--------|-------------|------------|-----------|
| box_1  | apple       | user       | user_a    |
| box_2  | orange      | office     | office_a  |
| box_3  | banana      | import     | import_a  |
| box_4  | pear        | storage    | storage_a |

| box_source |
|------------|
| user       |
| office     |
| import     |
| storage    |
```