# Composite Foreign key to single primary key

Tags: database-design, schema

How do I create a composite foreign key to a table with a single primary key? For example suppose I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Branches (
    BranchId UniqueIdentifier DEFAULT NewSequentialID(), 
    CONSTRAINT pk_BranchId PRIMARY KEY (BranchId)
);

CREATE TABLE Expectations (
    ExpectationId UniqueIdentifier DEFAULT NewSequentialID(), 
    BranchId UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT fk_Expectations_BranchId FOREIGN KEY (BranchId) REFERENCES Branches(BranchId), 
    CONSTRAINT pk_ExpectationId PRIMARY KEY (ExpectationId)
);

CREATE TABLE ClassSections (
    ClassId UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL,
    BranchId UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT fk_ClassSections_ClassId FOREIGN KEY (ClassId) REFERENCES Classes(ClassId), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_ClassSections_BranchId FOREIGN KEY (BranchId) REFERENCES Branches(BranchId), 
    CONSTRAINT pk_ClassSections PRIMARY KEY (ClassID, BranchId)
);

CREATE TABLE ClassExpectations (
    ClassId UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL, 
    BranchId UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL, 
    ExpectationId UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT fk_ClassExpectations_ClassId FOREIGN KEY (ClassId) REFERENCES Classes(ClassId), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_ClassExpectations_BranchId FOREIGN KEY (BranchId) REFERENCES Branches(BranchId), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_ClassExpectations_ExpectationId FOREIGN KEY (ExpectationId) REFERENCES Expectations(ExpectationId), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_ClassExpectations_ExpectationIdBranchId FOREIGN KEY (ExpectationId, BranchId) REFERENCES Expectations(ExpectationId, BranchId), 
    CONSTRAINT pk_ClassDueDates PRIMARY KEY (ClassId, ExpectationId)
);
```

I'm trying to add the following constraint, but it won't allow me:

```
ALTER TABLE ClassExpectations ADD CONSTRAINT fk_ClassExpectations_ExpectationIdBranchId FOREIGN KEY (ExpectationId, BranchId) REFERENCES Expectations(ExpectationId, BranchId);
```

I keep getting the error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'Expectations' that match the referencing column list in the foreign
>   key

How else do I ensure that an ExpectationId is never added to ClassExpectations without its corresponding BranchId (from the Expectations table)?

Comment: It seems very similar, if not identical to the problem at this Q: [Many to Many and Weak Entities](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities) You will only need 2 foreign keys in `ClassExpectations`, not 4, both composite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is a little bit like the old joke: "Doctor, doctor! It hurts when I do *this*."

If you want a foreign key to an entity then that entity needs to have a unique key defined to be referenced.

The fact that your `Expectations` table has a unique candidate key in `Expectations.ExpectationId` should not prevent you from defining another candidate key that combines ExpectationId and BranchId.  This seems like a violation of third normal form, and technically it is.  However, that is only true because you happen to define ExpectationId as unique.  You could have defined ExpectationId as a sequence within BranchId, such that ExpectationId is not unique on its own.  As it is, you can think of it as the `Expectation` table defining the *combination* of two unique values as being the fact of interest.

In any case, if you want to define a foreign key to `Expectation` that is the combination of `ExpectationId` and `BranchId` then there is no way around it but to define the primary key that way.