# Can I somehow Improve the relationships between tables in the following sample?

Tags: database-design

I am currently developing a database for a school management system... There are tables for `GRADE`, `SECTION` and `SHIFT`...

```
GRADE
====
id PRIMARY KEY

SECTION
====
id PRIMARY KEY

SHIFT
====
id PRIMARY KEY
```

And yet another table which comprises such data called `GROUP` through foreign keys which additionally has a primary key...

```
GROUP
====
id PRIMARY KEY
grade_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GRADE(id)
section_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SECTION(id)
shift_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SHIFT(id)
```

Now where I have an desing stigma and would like advice from a designer with more experience... A table called `SUBJECT` which comprises a foreign key referencing `GRADE` and a primary key (A certain grade always has the same subjects)...

```
SUBJECT
====
id PRIMARY KEY
grade_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GRADE(id)
```

Now I have yet another table called `CLASS` referencing `SUBJECT`, `PROFESSOR` and `GROUP` through a foreign key too in addition to its primary key...

```
CLASS
====
id PRIMARY KEY
subject_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SUBJECT(id)
professor_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PROFESSOR(id)
group_id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GROUP(id)
```

I wonder if it is ok that if drilling down one level on `CLASS` table references makes possible to access presumably the same `GRADE` (Through `SUBJECT` and `GROUP`) in two different ways. I don't include the code for the tables because I do think it would make this question somewhat long and of course there are more tables. My database is already implemented and works  with the proper application but I would like to see if design could be improved. Thanks in advance. *Note : I know I am using reserved words for table names in my case elaboration, but only for illustrative purposes, also did not include all the tables... Too I have an `STUDENT` table which as a reference to a `GROUP`, that is why I included a primary key on such table. I hope now my question is better explained, I am new to this kind of site.

Comment: A question like this can use a simple schema diagram. Most db these days have this feature to dump a schema diagram. It does not make it long, only clearer.

Comment: @ Renzo Well, each GROUP represesnts a collection of STUDENT, it is defined by a GRADE (Current level of education), a SHIFT (Denoting the working hours) and a SECTION (There can be many groups of the same level) an unique combination of these, each STUDENT can only belong to a GROUP. A CLASS as an schedule bit indicating a PROFESSOR, SIGNATURE and GROUP. I hope this help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asssuming that I have understood the problem, the following picture describes (a part of) your database, in which an arrow from `A` to `B` corresponds to a foreign key from table `A`to table `B`:

[image]

Actually, there is a redundancy in that `Grades` are referred both by `Groups` and `Subjects` *and* each class *must* have the *same* grade if it is accessed through one of the two relations.

I think that in a case like this you have two options:

1. Keep this schema, and check, maybe with a trigger, that when you insert a class it refers to a course and a subject with the same grade, or
2. change the schema, removing from `Subject` the foreign key to `Grade`, and, if you need to find the grade of a certain subject, joining that table with classes, courses and grades. In this way you simplify the situation, but you could create subjects not tied to specific grades.

I have a light preference for the first solution: in both of them, however, it is important that the objects in tables `Grade`, `Subject`, `Course` and `Classes` be inserted with great attention to not cause inconsistencies. The best way to do this is to define in the database stored procedures to operate on more than one object and/or perform all the proper checks, and require that the application(s) use only them, without inserting explicitly records.

Comment: There is another way, as described in this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities/34050#34050