# Indirect constraints (foreign keys amongst three/four tables)

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, constraint

I have the next layout of tables:

```
table COMPANY:
- primary key pk_company

table USERS:
- primary key pk_users, 
- foreign key (fk_company) references COMPANY (pk_company)

table GROUPS: <br>
- primary key pk_group,
- foreign key (fk_company) references COMPANY (pk_company)

table ROLES:
- primary key pk_role

table RELATIO_UGR:
- foreign key (fk_user) references USERS (pk_user)
- foreign key (fk_group) references GROUPS (pk_group)
- foreign key (fk_role) references ROLES (pk_role)
- Also: UNIQUE KEY [fk_user,fk_group]
```

This is:

```
USER ---(n:m)--- GROUP ---(m:1)--- COMPANY
USER ------------(n:1)------------ COMPANY
1 company can have N users (workers)
1 company can have M groups
M groups can have N users (each worker can be in more than one group)
1 user can have only 1 role (read / read-write / admin) in each group.
```

The thing is that all constraints seem to work in the individual tables, however, the `RELATIO_UGR` table fails to establish constraints.

Let's suppose we have:

- USER1 from GROUP1 and COMPANY1
- USER2 from GROUP2 and COMPANY2

The `RELATIO_UGR` shouldn't allow me to establish (for example) the relationship:

- `USER2-GROUP1-COMPANY2`

Yet, I CAN `insert` it...

How do I restrict it?

Comment: See this question and answer: [Many to Many and Weak Entities](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities/34050#34050). Solution is to add `pk_company` in the `relatio_ugr` table and adjust foreign keys accordingly (and add unique keys in `users` and `groups`).

Comment: I forgot to say that relatio_ugr already defines a unique key (fk_user,fk_group). Yet, I still have the problem.

Comment: Please check the linked question and answer. It's essentially the same problem.

Comment: The `unique (user, group)` is for the *"1 user can have only 1 role (read / read-write / admin) in each group"* constraint. This should be kept, it's not related to the issue.

Comment: Sorry I missed the link. I'll read it carefully. thanks.

Comment: Yesterday I had no time for testing the solution but today I did and obviously works perfectly. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your business rules will dictate your schema modeling. It is important you establish all these rules first. 
If a user can belong to multiple Group (group 1 , group 2, group3) than it is the rule. If you don't want a user to be able to be inserted in a group that belongs to another company, you need to program this logic at the application layer. FK itself only checks the key exists in parent on insertion. (it does not verify for you if that user is from group 1 or 2). If you want to enforce this, i would recommend using triggers and using a userGroup table:

```
USER ------------(n:1)------------ COMPANY
USER ---(n:m)--- UserGROUP --(n:m)---- Group---(m:1)--- COMPANY

UserGROUP (group_id,user_id, roleId) 
(PK on group_id, userId to enforce 1 user role per group) 

Trigger On insert in UserGROUP:
 if user.company_id = group_company_id, then insert else "error".
```

Comment: mmm... sounds interesting. I'll give it a try... I'll tell you in a while. Thanks

Comment: Finally I didn't have time yesterday for learning about triggers as much as I wanted. Anyway, I solved the problem with the post of "Many to Many and Weak Entities" that ypercube posted. ---- HOWEVER, I didn't know of the existence of TRIGGERS and I found them really interesting, since I have some maintenance to do in the database and your hint offered me a good chance of solving that maintenance... so... THANK YOU VERY MUCH :)