# Constraint across multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, referential-integrity

I'm modeling a system where with vendors, each of which sells some overlapping subset of products available in the universe. Products (T-shirt) come in various variants (Small, Medium, Large) with generic (size) and vendor-specific (Item code) attributes. There is also vendor-specific information about the Products themselves which doesn't vary by size (e.g., their manufacturer).

I've got four tables involved:

```
VendorProduct (vendor_id, product_id, manufacturer)
Product (product_id, name)
Variant (variant_id, product_id, size)
VendorVariant (variant_id, vendor_id, item_code)
```

I'd like my database to enforce a constraint that every VendorVariant has an associated VendorProduct, which could be found with this query:

```
select * from vendor_variants 
  inner join variants on variants.variant_id = vendor_variants.variant_id
  inner join products on products.product_id = variants.product_id
  inner join vendor_products on vendor_products.product_id = products.product_id AND
               vendor_products.vendor_id = vendor_variants.vendor_id
```

Can I do this in Postgres without changing the table structure? If no, are there tricks to model the data differently to allow this type of constraint?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be sure that for every VendorProductVariant the associated vendor and product (which can be found through the Variant table) are actually associated themselves (there is a row in the VendorProduct)?

Comment: Exactly. I'm using foreign key constraints to ensure a VendorProductVariant has a Variant, a Variant has a product, and a VendorProduct has a Product. What I can't do is ensure a VendorProductVariant always has a VendorProduct with the same vendor when you go through the chain.

Comment: Then no way without changing the tables. If you can change the tables, you need to add the `product_id` in the `VendorProductVariant` and then modify the 2 FKs (to `Variant` and `VendorProduct`) to use composite keys, `(vendor_id, product_id)` and `(variant_id, product_id)` respectively. See a similar question: [Many to Many and Weak Entities](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities/34050#34050)

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ that's great advice (expand to an answer?) Should I use triggers or some other trick to automatically set `product_id` when creating a `VendorProductVariant` (since you can get it from the variant) or is that not the right path to go down?

Comment: If you add the `product_id` in the `VendorProductVariant` table, I don't see any reason for triggers.